# How can I use an "if statement" in combination with a date in Monarch?

Tags: datawatch-monarch

In Monarch I'm looking at two columns: column A and column B. I want to use an if statement with the following syntax:

```
IF([column A]>[column B],"",[column A])
```

But I can't get this to work, unless it's text (Ab format). But then it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `=IF(A1>B1,"",A1)` would work, where IF the value of A1 is greater than B1, a blank is returned, else A1 is returned

Comment: Right, I think the issue is that I have to convert the format from date to text (Ab), since I can't just put in the formula when both columns are dates. When it's text, it's not correctly working. The date 9/19/2018 > 7/28/2018 = blank space in the column (where it should be 9/19/2018)

Comment: It would work the other way round, a date is stored as a number, and your logic A1 > B1 would only work for a number and not text. to easily convert to a number use `=IF(A1+0 > B1+0 , "", A1)` this will leave everything in its original format, but do the conversion inside of the logic.

Comment: obviously my comment is relating to Excel, may be slightly different in DataWatch

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's not working in Monarch.

Comment: I added the tag and made you're question more readable. Not sure if it is necessary to write an answer but you might want to explain, what you mean by "but then it doesn't work as expected" and what exactly is in "Ab format". But again I don't know Monarch maybe it is unneeded information in order to understand the question correctly.

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles I don't really know much about the software (other then what I gather from their website, wikipedia, etc.), maybe you can provide me with some information to put in the tag wiki, or propose the it [yourself](https://superuser.com/tags/datawatch-monarch/info) right away?! Here, for example, is the information on the [MS-Excel-Tag](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

IF([column A]>[column B],ctod(""),[column A])

(Date format)